# rsnapshot / rsync protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, rsnapshot

on both computer same version of rsync:

```
rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
```

cat /etc/rsnapshot.conf

```
[...]
backup  root@IP:/etc/     localhost/      ssh_args=-i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -p 4378
[...]
```

protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [Receiver=3.1.2]

Comment: Is your shell clean?

Comment: I am facing the same error ... @MichaelHampton would you be able to elaborate on your comment? How to confirm whether shell is clean or not (pronbably it isn't) and (if not clean) how to make it clean again?